# Why is Windows 10 occasionally rendering some screens as black panels?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, optimus

Sometimes, when summoning a window, it looks like this:

[image: black window]

It isn't supposed to look like that - that is actually visual studio.

A couple of notes:

- My computer is a thinkpad W540 with Optimus technology. The discrete/integrated voodoo, while great in some instances, has caused no end of problems in the past, so this is major culprit
- My setup is a bit monitor mad - 2xWQXGA 30" screens + the 15" laptop screen which I run at WUXGA. I've just shown the one screen there

  - Sometimes this happens when I drag a window from one screen to the other. Sometimes when I just summon a window
  - Might be related to resume/suspend, which I do usually at least twice a day (work/home)
  - Can usually be fixed by dragging or resizing.
  - Other apps I've noticed it happening with include slack and paintdotnet
  - Sometimes I can drag in such a way that it sits on two monitors. On one monitor it will render correctly, on the other monitor it will be black. Unfortunately I haven't been able to screenshot this.

Does anybody know what is happening? This happens multiple times a day and is quite disruptive to productivity. My graphics drivers are up to date (i.e. using 10.18.13.544 dated 12/17/2015 on the Lenovo website.

Comment: I would search for a virus. which might trying to popup. also try to disable visual effects on windows. make it performance and try if you see it again. it might be a problem with resolution too. try to lower it.

Comment: I have a W541, same issue. It happens if I move a window from internal laptop display to external display *if hardware accelleration is used*. The drivers/windows don't handle the handover well when the gpu, that renders the window, switches.